# stdin from heredoc not printing to screen?

Tags: bash, zsh, heredoc

I have a program that interactively logins a user. I used the heredoc to automate the process.

```
./login <<EOF
user1@test.com
password
EOF
```

I was expecting the output would be something like this. This is what it displays when I run the program without the heredoc and type in username and password myself.

```
$ ./login
Enter your email: user1@test.com
Enter your password: password
Successfully logged in.
```

However, I only see this.

```
$ ./login
Enter your email: 
Enter your password: 
Successfully logged in.
```

As you can see, all of the heredoc inputs are not printed out, even though the program seems to be getting the stdin correctly. What's the reason for this? It would be great if I could still see those inputs to help me debug problems. Thanks.

Comment: You tagged both bash and zsh; are you using one, the other, or both? (It would seem your `./login` script would only be using one...

Comment: Seeing the input echoed to the terminal is a special case, when the terminal itself *is* standard input. Standard input in general does not get echoed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ECHO* is a feature of the tty when users manually type chars to the tty. Your `./login << ...` does not get input from the tty so the heredoc is not echoed. It's just like, for example,

```
grep something < /some/file
```

where you don't want it to *echo* the whole file's data.

Answer (score 1):

The `login` program disables the local echo (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html).

#### Update

If the `login` program is writen by you, then is much easier, just `echo` the values after reading them

Comment: The login program is written by me. I don't have any code to disable the echo. It is only reading from stdin.